# Select data based on XML attributes

Tags: oracle-12c

My table contain two columns: Branch and data

Here's an example:

Branch having value finance
 Data having value xml packet i.e.

```xml
<field id="0" value="2200"/>
              <field id="2" value="9048001001234567890"/>
              <field id="3" value="000000"/>
              <field id="4" currency="356" type="amount" value="100.00"/>
              <field id="7" value="0702175451"/>
              <field id="11" value="818317649211"/>
```

The data column contains some XML packet.  I want to select some particular data out of that XML.  For example, I want to select only the value of field id=4 (i.e. 100.00).

How can I do that?

Comment: I don't think that is a valid XML document.  I expect to see a "top level" XML tag.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your sample data and revised question: id=4  result 100.00

Table:

```
Create Table #tbl
(
id Int,
[data] xml
)
Insert Into #tbl Values
(1,'<field id="0" value="2200"/> <field id="2" value="9048001001234567890"/> <field id="3" value="000000"/> <field id="4" currency="356" type="amount" value="100.00"/> <field id="7" value="0702175451"/> <field id="11" value="818317649211"/> ')
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
       Cast(d.value('(./@value)[1]', 'VarChar(20)') As Decimal(10,2)) AS yourdata
FROM 
       #tbl 
       CROSS APPLY [data].nodes('/field') t(d)
Where  d.value('(./@id)[1]', 'Int') = 4
```

Result:

```
yourdata
100.00
```

Comment: It showing invalid table name

Answer (score 0):

If the following (SQL SERVER) does not hit the mark, please include your sample data and expected output. I'm not sure what you reference with [Branch data Finance].  Based on your second sentence, I created a table with 2 columns where the 1st column is your id and the second is your xml data.  The query retrieves the 'data' where the id=26

Table:

```
Create Table #tbl
(
id Int,
[data] xml
)
Insert Into #tbl Values
(1,'<yourecord><data>1111</data></yourecord>'),
(26,'<yourecord><data>4879</data></yourecord>'),
(35,'<yourecord><data>9999</data></yourecord>')
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
       id,
       d.value('(./data)[1]', 'VARCHAR(500)') AS yourdata
FROM 
       #tbl 
       CROSS APPLY [data].nodes('/yourecord') t(d)
Where id = 26

    Drop Table #tbl
```

Result:

```
id  yourdata
26  4879
```

Comment: You can edit your original answer.  Also, with three "oracle" tags and one "sql-server" tag, I suspect the OP is on Oracle, not SQL Server.